# Trying to parse XML from URL to PickerView with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xml, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to parse XML with XMLParser and put it on a PickerView. This is my code:

Main code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, XMLParserDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Button: UIButton!

    var arrayCategorias = [Categories]()

    var parser = XMLParser()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlString = URL(string: "http://thecatapi.com/api/categories/list")
        self.parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: urlString!)!
        let success:Bool = self.parser.parse()
        parser.delegate = self
        if success {
            print("success")
        } else {
            print("parse failure!")
        }

        print(arrayCategorias.count)
    }

    @IBAction func botonPulsado(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
        if(elementName=="category")
        {
            let categoria = Categories()
            for string in attributeDict {
                let strvalue = string.value as NSString
                switch string.key {
                case "id":
                    categoria.id = strvalue.integerValue
                    break
                case "name":
                    categoria.name = strvalue as String
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
            arrayCategorias.append(categoria)
        }

        func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        }

        func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        }

        func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {
            print("failure error: ", parseError)
        }
    }
}
```

Class Categories Code:

```
import Foundation

class Categories{
     var id: Int = 0
     var name: String = ""
 }
```

I don't know exactly what the problem is, but when I try to read `arrayCategorias()` just to see if there is any data, it just shows me 0. And where I catch the error, it shows me: "parse failure".

If anyone can help me, I'm just an android programmer and I don't know why it doesn't work.

I need help with putting the data on the PickerView.

Comment: Start by moving out the last 3 parser delegate methods from within the 1st parser delegate method.

Comment: what do you mean..? @rmaddy

Comment: And how I should do it? I'm trying to figure it out my self, but, I don't know, as I said, it's my first program with swift, and it s*cks for real.. you have any example with an app like this? @Rob

Comment: @SantiAlbus You have functions inside another function. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of issues:

1. You have set your `delegate` after you parsed, whereas you must do this before you call `parse()`.
2. You have some of your delegate methods implemented inside `didStartElement`. These need to be top level methods of your parser delegate.
3. Minor unrelated issue, but your class name of `Categories` isn't quite right, because it represents a single "category", not many. So I'd rename this to be `Category`. (I'd personally also make it a `struct`, but that's up to you.)
4. Your `id` and `name` values are not attributes of the `category` element. They are their own elements, so you have to parse them separately (using `foundCharacters` and build the `Category` object on `didEndElement` of `category`.
5. The `id` of the categories appears to be an integer, so I'd make the `id` of `Category` an `Int`.
6. You're calling `parse()` of a `XMLParser` that is using a URL from the main thread. That's inadvisable because you're blocking the main thread while it does the request. Personally, I'd use `URLSession` to request the data asynchronously, process it on a background queue, and only dispatch the final update of the model object and UI update to the main queue.

   Personally, I'd adopt asynchronous patterns myself with `@escaping` completion handlers, to help isolate UI updates that I trigger after a parse from the parsing itself
7. A stylistic matter, but I wouldn't put all of this `XMLParserDelegate` code in the view controller. At the very least, put it in an extension so it's nicely organized. Even better, define a stand-alone parser delegate object in the spirit of the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and ensuring that you're not accidentally updating view controller model objects while the UI might be referring to it. It more safely ensures thread-safety and keeps your code more nicely encapsulated.

Pulling this all together, you could do something like:

```
struct Category {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    
    var categories = [Category]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        startRequestAndParse() { categories, error in
            guard let categories = categories, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }
            
            // if you got here, everything is OK, so update model and UI on main thread
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.categories = categories
                print(self.categories)
                
                // trigger whatever UI update you want here, too;
                
                self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// Initiate request from server and parse results
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - completion: This is called when the request/parsing is done. This may be called
    ///                         on background thread. If parsing failed, the array of categories
    ///                         will be `nil` and we should have `error`.
    ///     - categories: First parameter of the `completion` closure is the array of `Category` objects, or `nil` on error.
    ///     - error:      Second parameter of the `completion` closure is the resulting `Error`, if any.

    private func startRequestAndParse(completion: @escaping (_ categories: [Category]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: "http://thecatapi.com/api/categories/list")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            
            // ok, now parse
            
            let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
            let delegate = ParserDelegate()
            parser.delegate = delegate
            parser.parse()
            
            completion(delegate.categories, parser.parserError)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

// this assumes you set the picker's `delegate` to be the view controller (either in IB or programmatically in `viewDidLoad`

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return categories[row].name
    }
}

// this assumes you set the picker's `dataSource` to be the view controller (either in IB or programmatically in `viewDidLoad`

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }
}

/// Parser delegate for categories

class ParserDelegate: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
    private var id: Int?
    private var name: String?
    private var value: String?
    
    var categories: [Category]?
    
    // initialize `categories`
    
    func parserDidStartDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
        categories = []
    }
    
    // if `id` or `name`, initialize `value` so we'll capture the appropriate value
    
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
        if elementName == "id" || elementName == "name" {
            value = ""
        }
    }
    
    // if `value` is not `nil`, go ahead and concatenate the additional characters
    
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        value? += string
    }
    
    // if `id` or `name`, update the appropriate property
    // if `category`, build a `Category` object and add it to our array
    // regardless, reset `value` to `nil`
    
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        switch elementName {
        case "id":
            if let value = value {
                id = Int(value)
            }
        case "name":
            name = value
        case "category":
            if let id = self.id, let name = self.name {
                categories!.append(Category(id: id, name: name))
            }
            id = nil
            name = nil
        default:
            ()
        }
        value = nil
    }
    
    // if any error, reset `categories` so caller knows there was an issue
    
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {
        categories = nil
    }
    
}
```